# Npm run dev opens notepad

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix, npm-scripts, laravel-nova

I have a fresh installation of laravel 9 and nova 4 where i try to create a new resource tool. When i try to run npm run dev or npm run watch, it opens notepad with the mix file instead of compiling. I am running on Windows 11 Home.

https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/3844

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `mix watch` from the command line?

Comment: Hi Keith. Mix watch does not seem to do anything (command not found). I did try npm run watch with the same result as above.